# How to go about correcting space in first name in US Passport

Tags: passports, paperwork, us-citizens

In my current passport, it has my first name as "**firstname**" but in my other identification such as driver license, bank account, social security card, I had my first name as "**first name**" (with a space in between). I had flown a few times within the US and didn't had issue with the passport. My passport is expiring next year, I am now applying for a US passport renewal, will the space discrepancy give me any issue on the passport renewal?

Should I stick to first name without space or try to change the name to with space? What sort of evidence will I need to provide?

Edit: to respond to some of the comments and some more detail that may help or clarify: I was born in China, and immigrated to US, not sure if the Chinese birth certificate will help. I obtain the passport through naturalization of my parent. When I first submitted the application for passport my parent was saying there shouldn't be a space because some reason I can't remembered, so on the first passport application my first name didn't have space. Then the application went through and I got my passport. at that time I didn't paid too much attention, and this passport didn't gave me issue during travel and other things and I just let it go, until now, its probably time to set things straight.

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows the rules for US Passports will give a real answer. But I am compelled to make sure you (and anyone reading this) is aware of the [problems with names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you list what documents, such as birth certificate etc., that uses your "**first name**". Is the passport the only document that uses "**firstname**"?

Comment: Why does the passport not have a space?  Why didn't you get it corrected when it was first issued?

Comment: What is your actual first name as listed on your birth certificate?

Comment: Sounds like [Change of name through usage](https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/u-s-passports/change-name-on-u-s-passport/) might be the way to go

Comment: How is your name written on the naturalization certificate?

Comment: The name in Chinese might not help as the writing system is so different.  Spaces are not usual between character.  Transliterations vary.  Spaces between all characters used to common.  Dropping spaces is becoming more popular.  E.g. 毛泽东 as Mao Ze Dong or Mao Zedong.  The Chinese has not changed.